# For every string get unique combination of 3 chars (together)

Tags: python

If I have string like `"combination.py"`, I want to get the following result using Python:

```
["com" , "omb", "mbi", "bin", "ina", "nat" , "ati" , "tio", "ion", "on.", "n.p" , ".py"]
```

I have something that is working quite good, but it's a really long code, so I'm looking for something short and beautiful. :)

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be missing a few-- was that an output of your current code, is there another criterion, or is that merely a typo?

Comment: @DSM: I think everything is there, now…

Comment: one item was missing indeed -> edited it

Comment: @JohnDoeTheOne: If one of the answers suits you, you can earn reputation, and also direct interested readers to it by marking it as accepted (by clicking on the check mark beside the answer). :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> s = "combination.py" 
>>> [s[i:i+3] for i in range(len(s)-2)]
['com', 'omb', 'mbi', 'bin', 'ina', 'nat', 'ati', 'tio', 'ion', 'on.', 'n.p', '.py']
```

It is indeed a good habit to look for something "short and beautiful". Python is quite apt at this. :)

Comment: Guys you are great, all comments are great, thanks for helping me, it really helps a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

The function

```
def substrings(s, l=3):
    return [s[k:k+l] for k in range(len(s)-l+1)]
```

called like

```
substrings("combination.py")
```

yields

```
['com', 'omb', 'mbi', 'bin', 'ina', 'nat', 'ati', 'tio', 'ion', 'on.', 'n.p', '.py']
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is

```
for i in range(0, len(a)-2):
    print a[i:i+3];
```

when `a` is a string.

Comment: The `0` in `range(0,…)` is really useless: `range(len(a)-2)` does the exact same thing.

Answer (score -3):

```
    String txt = "combination.py";
for(int i=0;i<txt.length;i++){
  String result = txt.substring(i,i+2)
  System.out.println(result);
  i+=3;
}
```

Comment: This is neither Python nor Pythonic. Edit: Nor would it give the desired result.